# NSMutableDictionary setting value causes crash

Tags: crash, nsmutabledictionary

```
NSMutableDictionary             *firstCurr;

NSLog(@"currency list count=%d",[self.currencyList count]);

for (int j=0; j<[self.currencyList count]; j++)
{
NSLog(@"j=%d",j);
firstCurr                   =   [self.currencyList objectAtIndex:j];
[firstCurr                      setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:     [[currencyItems objectAtIndex:j]floatValue]] forKey:kSelectedCurrencyINR];
}
```

i have an array of nsmutabledictionary objects called currency list, i am trying to set one field of the nsmutabledictionary.
 Accessing the firstCurr in the marked line causes crash!

```
NSMutableArray                          *arr;
arr                                 =   [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]  setObject:arr forKey:kSelectedCurrencies];
```

this is how i add in the array

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

[dict setValue:countryCode[pos] forKey:kSelectedCurrencyCode];
[dict setValue:countryName[pos] forKey:kSelectedCurrencyCountry];
[dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0] forKey:kSelectedCurrencyINR];
[dict setValue:currencyName[pos] forKey:kSelectedCurrencyName];
[temp addObject:dict];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:temp forKey:kSelectedCurrencies];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: You should be getting something, a stack trace, an exception etc.

Comment: -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object' this is what i get when i run it one device

Comment: Probably means that the dictionaries in your `currencyList` array are `NSDictionary` type objects, not `NSMutableDictionary` type objects.  do you have and code for where you are adding things to the `currencyList`?

Comment: That is how you are presumably creating the array, but how are you adding objects to that array

Comment: Well it seems to be working when you initially create it, try changing the first line to `NSMutableDictionary *dict = ...`  Perhaps once it gets added to the array it is converting it to a non-mutable dictionary

Comment: even after changing its the same exception '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12168/discussion-between-dan-f-and-raghul)

Comment: I solved it by creating a mutable copy                          firstCurr                   =   [[[self.currencyList objectAtIndex:j] mutableCopy] autorelease]; and then finally replacing the object in array [self.currencyList replaceObjectAtIndex:j withObject:firstCurr];